# I want to Dynamically Create Select list when i click a button by using struts2 tag?

Tags: struts2

I want to Dynamically Create  Drop down list when i click a Button and the value selected in the Drop Down List should be inserted into the Database The Drop Down List should be in Struts2 Tag.

Answer (score 0):

```
function addDropDown(parent){

        var myselect = document.createElement("select");
        myselect.setAttribute("name","someName");
        myselect.onchange=function(){ submitvalue(this.value) };


        theOption=document.createElement("OPTION");
        theText=document.createTextNode("text gere1");
        theOption.appendChild(theText);
        theOption.setAttribute("value","value here1");
        myselect.appendChild(theOption);

        theOption=document.createElement("OPTION");
        theText=document.createTextNode("text gere2");
        theOption.appendChild(theText);
        theOption.setAttribute("value","value gere2");
        myselect.appendChild(theOption);

        theOption=document.createElement("OPTION");
        theText=document.createTextNode("text gere3");
        theOption.appendChild(theText);
        theOption.setAttribute("value","value gere3");
        myselect.appendChild(theOption);

        parent,appendChild(myselect);

}
```

call this function onClick of your button with some parent element(form or div) as argument.The function submitvalue() will be called on selection of any element of the dropdown, do your database submit action there(submit using ajax or whatever you are using as you have not mentioned it). I also noticed you have mentioned that the dropdown should be in struts2 tags, icouldnt wonder why as even the static struts2 tags get changed to html tags when executed